# Event listeners/onclick events for buttons created in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript button (button A), when it is clicked, it generates some new elements, including another button (button B). I would like a way to listen on button B, and then execute a separate function.

I tried editing Button B's 'onclick' attribute in javascript. This did not work.

HTML:

```
 <input id="addTaskButton" type="submit" value="add task" onclick="addTaskFunction()"></input>
```

Javascript:

```
function buttonB()
{
// Not working
}

function addTaskFunction()
{
 var doneButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 doneButton.id = "doneButton";
 doneButton.innerHTML = "DONE";
 doneButton.onclick = "buttonB()";
}
```

i am expecting the listener to perform buttonB when ran. Instead, i get no response.

Comment: true usage is = doneButton.onclick = buttonB;

Comment: Perfect, it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript to create a button with onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650975/javascript-to-create-a-button-with-onclick)

Comment: Glad that helped. I added it as a reply. Please accept the my answer also :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add onclick event while creating an element with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846492/how-to-add-onclick-event-while-creating-an-element-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct use is as follows

```
function addTaskFunction()
{
 var doneButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 doneButton.id = "doneButton";
 doneButton.innerHTML = "DONE";
 doneButton.onclick = buttonB;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
doneButton.onclick = function(){buttonB()};
```